# <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=sessionTimedOut.jspx"/> Ignored

Tags: jsf, weblogic, oracle-adf, jspx

I have a development environment on my machine and a remote shared development environment. Both have "identically" configured WebLogic 10.3 servers. However, on my local dev environment, the below meta tag works as expected. Upon being deployed to the mirroring WebLogic 10.3 server, the meta tag no longer works.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=sessionTimedOut.jspx"/>
```

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <f:view>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=sessionTimedOut.jspx"/>
    <af:document id="d1" title="#{backing_login.appTitle} - Logged Out">
    <af:resource type="javascript"/>
</af:document>
</f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: The installation is essentially the default installation. The only modifications we've made to the configuration is that we created a domain to deploy the application on to, configured JDBC connections and increased the memory allotment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem turned out to be Internet Explorer 9 Zone Security settings. The 'Allow META REFRESH' option was enabled for intranet sites, but disabled for external sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <f:view>
   <af:document id="d1" title="#{backing_login.appTitle} - Logged Out">
     <af:resource type="javascript"/>
     <f:facet name="metaContainer">
       <af:outputText value="&lt;meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; URL=sessionTimedOut.jspx' />" 
                      escape="false" />
     </f:facet>
   </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your method. It did not work with the Internet Explorer 9 Zone settings set to disable Meta Refresh. Once, I enabled that settings, both your method and the meta tag worked properly.